# How to create a linux shell command from a github repo?

Tags: linux, github

I am trying to add https://github.com/RubinLab/aimconvert to my /bin so I can run it like a linux command. How can I do this?

Comment: This sounds like a question better suited for SuperUser or the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note for the OP, this is obviously 100% compatible with Stack Overflow. Simply edit your question to show exactly what you type, and the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

From the README, you can first execute it locally within your local cloned repository

```
git clone https://github.com/RubinLab/aimconvert
cd aimconvert/bin
./aimconvert xml2json inputDirPath outputDirPath
```

> will convert every xml in `inputDirPath` to json and puts in `outputDirPath`.
> Creates `outputDirPath` if it doesn't exist

I recommend testing it that way first, because the [`bin/aimconvert`](https://github.com/RubinLab/aimconvert/blob/88b4796c441cbdee86a54be3ed4aa956c79a1336/bin/aimconvert#L2) is based on a relative path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../')();
```

So adding directly `bin/aimconvert` to your `/bin` might not work.

Comment: I tried running `$ ./bin/aimconvert xml2json ~/Desktop/lidc/ ~/Desktop/` in the aimconvert/bin directory, but I got the output `zsh: no such file or directory: ./bin/aimconvert`

Comment: @j.doe True, that was a wrong copy/paste. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I also ran `$  ./bin/aimconvert xml2json ~/Desktop/lidc/ ~/Desktop/ ` in the aimconvert directory, but that gives me this output `env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: I just tried the updated code, and it gives me the same env: node: error

Comment: @j.doe Is node in your $PATH?